# Parse JSON foreach with JS, shows HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am currently trying to parse a JSON with JavaScript. My issue is that I'd like the output to look like this:

```
<li>AppName1</li>
<li>AppName2</li>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

However it just does not work and I don't know how to achieve that. This is the object deserialized from the JSON response:

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "AppId": 1,
    "AppName": "AppName1",
    "AppSize": "2.1"
  }, {
    "AppId": 2,
    "AppName": "AppName2",
    "AppSize": ""
  }]
}
```

This is my .js file:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = myObj.AppName;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This is in my HTML file

```
<p id="test"></p>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I really cannot seem to understand this a single bit. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please put a copy of the JSON in your question rather than a link that may not exist later.  Do you want both a pure JavaScript answer and a jQuery one?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Did so! JavaScript is preferred but a jQuery answer could be both helpful and interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that you can only have `li` elements as children of `<ul>` or `<ol>`, so the `p` element needs to be changed.

The `AppName` property is part of the objects within `data`, so you will need to either loop through them:

```
myObj.data.forEach(function(o) {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += '<li>' + o.AppName + '</li>';
}
```

Or access them, individually by index:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<li>' + myObj.data[0].AppName + '</li>'; // first item only
```

```js
var myObj = {
  "data": [{
    "AppId": 3,
    "AppName": "AnimojiStudio",
    "AppSlug": "animojistudio",
    "AppIcon": "https:\/\/img.lmdinteractive.pro\/icons\/animojistudio.png",
    "AppUrl": "https:\/\/ipa.lmdinteractive.pro\/ipa\/appstore\/animojistudio.ipa",
    "AppVersion": "1.2.2",
    "AppSize": "2.1"
  }, {
    "AppId": 2,
    "AppName": "Cute Cut Pro",
    "AppSlug": "cute-cut-pro",
    "AppIcon": "http:\/\/is2.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Purple118\/v4\/03\/70\/69\/03706968-2399-a1d8-e7c4-12897394ead9\/source\/512x512bb.jpg",
    "AppUrl": "https:\/\/ipa.lmdinteractive.pro\/ipa\/appstore\/cutecutpro.ipa",
    "AppVersion": "",
    "AppSize": ""
  }]
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<li>' + myObj.data[0].AppName + '</li>';
```

```html
<ul id="test"><li>
```

Comment: Could you explain the loop a little further? I don't really understand how the loop works with the objects! Thank you so much for your answer though, it helped me out a ton so far!

Comment: It's a [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. It iterates over every element in the array, executing the function you provide on each one. Within that function the argument provided is the current element in the iteration. In the case of the above example, it's the `o` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `forEach` loop and `append`. Inserting `li` inside a `p tag` is not a good idea even though it works. Convert the `p` into a `ul/ol`

```js
var data = {
  "data": [{
    "AppId": 3,
    "AppName": "AnimojiStudio",
    "AppSlug": "animojistudio",
    "AppIcon": "https:\/\/img.lmdinteractive.pro\/icons\/animojistudio.png",
    "AppUrl": "https:\/\/ipa.lmdinteractive.pro\/ipa\/appstore\/animojistudio.ipa",
    "AppVersion": "1.2.2",
    "AppSize": "2.1"
  }, {
    "AppId": 2,
    "AppName": "Cute Cut Pro",
    "AppSlug": "cute-cut-pro",
    "AppIcon": "http:\/\/is2.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Purple118\/v4\/03\/70\/69\/03706968-2399-a1d8-e7c4-12897394ead9\/source\/512x512bb.jpg",
    "AppUrl": "https:\/\/ipa.lmdinteractive.pro\/ipa\/appstore\/cutecutpro.ipa",
    "AppVersion": "",
    "AppSize": ""
  }]
}
data.data.forEach(e =>$('#test').append('<li>' + e.AppName + '</li>' + "<br>"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test"></ul>
```

Comment: There are very few times where document.write is a good idea. In fact more often than not it's very bad practice - as in this case. Do not use it here. Not least of all because you're just dumping the `li` elements in the middle of the DOM, not in any specific container.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of the `AppName` properties, you could do something like the below with jQuery. See the comments in the code for details:

```js
// Below is the JSON string from the OP's link
let json = '{"data":[{"AppId":3,"AppName":"AnimojiStudio","AppSlug":"animojistudio","AppIcon":"https:\/\/img.lmdinteractive.pro\/icons\/animojistudio.png","AppUrl":"https:\/\/ipa.lmdinteractive.pro\/ipa\/appstore\/animojistudio.ipa","AppVersion":"1.2.2","AppSize":"2.1"},{"AppId":2,"AppName":"Cute Cut Pro","AppSlug":"cute-cut-pro","AppIcon":"http:\/\/is2.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Purple118\/v4\/03\/70\/69\/03706968-2399-a1d8-e7c4-12897394ead9\/source\/512x512bb.jpg","AppUrl":"https:\/\/ipa.lmdinteractive.pro\/ipa\/appstore\/cutecutpro.ipa","AppVersion":"","AppSize":""}]}';

// Parse the JSON string into a JS object
json = JSON.parse(json);
let html = "";

// Loop over the object and append a list item for each AppName property.
$.each(json.data, function (index, item) {
    html += "<li>" + item.AppName + "</li>";
});

// Append the list to the div.
$("#container").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() since you have an array inside myObj. What you want to do is returning a li with AppName value

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var ul = document.getElementById("myUl");
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var data = myObj.data;
    data.map(app => {
        li.textContent = app.AppName;
        ul.appendChild(li);
    })
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work for me. Throws back this error: null is not an object (evaluating 'ul.appendChild')

Answer (score 0):

You have your object, and it is parsed so let's concentrate on doing something with that object:

```
var myObj = {
  "data": [{
    "AppId": 1,
    "AppName": "AppName1",
    "AppSize": "2.1"
  }, {
    "AppId": 2,
    "AppName": "AppName2",
    "AppSize": ""
  }]
};
```

Now we have that, let's use it in different ways.  `myObj` contains an array called `data` here.  That array is an array of JavaScript objects, each with properties like "AppId", "AppName" etc. which we can access either directly or through an index.  So, let's put up some examples of how to do that.  Comments in the code

```js
var myObj = {
  "data": [{
    "AppId": 1,
    "AppName": "AppName1",
    "AppSize": "2.1"
  }, {
    "AppId": 2,
    "AppName": "AppName2",
    "AppSize": ""
  }]
};
// Here I create a Bootstrap tab and contents
// call to create a new element on the DOM
function additem(item) {
  let lt = $('#list-tab');
  let ltc = $('#debug-tabContent');
  let thing = item.name;
  let thingId = "list-" + thing;
  let thingTabId = thingId + "-list";
  let ttab = $('<a />')
    .addClass('list-group-item list-group-item-action')
    .data('toggle', "list")
    .prop("id", thingTabId)
    .attr('role', 'tab')
    .prop('href', '#' + thingId)
    .html(item.name);
  ttab.appendTo(lt);
  let lc = $('<div />')
    .addClass('tab-pane fade')
    .prop("id", thingId)
    .attr('role', 'tabpanel')
    .text(JSON.stringify(item.obj));
  // .text("test");
  lc.appendTo(ltc);
}
// * cheat, put the objects in a bootstrap tab content list
additem({
  name: "myObj",
  obj: myObj
});
additem({
  name: "myObjW",
  obj: window["myObj"]
});
additem({
  name: "data",
  obj: myObj.data
});
additem({
  name: "data0",
  obj: myObj.data[0]
});
additem({
  name: "AppName",
  obj: myObj.data[0].AppName
});

// pure JS walk
// Here I create a LI list as a Bootstrap list group
let len = myObj.data.length;
let myP = document.getElementById("test");
let myReg = document.getElementById("mylist-reg");
let newUl = document.createElement("ul");
newUl.classList.add('list-group');
newUl.classList.add('list-group-primary');
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let newContent = document.createTextNode(myObj.data[i].AppName);
  newLi.appendChild(newContent);
  newLi.setAttribute("id", "app-" + myObj.data[i].AppId); //has to be unique
  newLi.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item");
  newUl.appendChild(newLi);
}
// put the list after the paragraph
document.body.insertBefore(newUl, myP);

let myLast = document.getElementById("app-2");
myLast.classList.add("active");
//activate the bootstrap tab clicks
$('#list-tab').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});

// just do it as strings
let html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  let textel = "<li id='app-js-" + myObj.data[i].AppId + "'>" + myObj.data[i].AppName + "</li>";
  html = html + textel;
}
myReg.innerHTML = html;

// jQuery, similar to prior
$.each(myObj.data, function(index, el) {
  let textel = "<li id='app-jq-" + el.AppId + "'>" + index + ":" + el.AppName + "</li>";
  $('#mylist-jq').append(textel);
});

// jQuery, similar to prior
$.each(myObj.data, function(index, el) {
  let elid = 'app-jq2-' + el.AppId;
  $("<li />").prop("id", elid).text(el.AppName)
    .appendTo('#mylist-jq2');
});
```

```css
.list-group-item {
  border: 1px lime solid
}

.list-item-last {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<ul id="mylist-reg"></ul>
<ul id="mylist-jq"></ul>
<ul id="mylist-jq2"></ul>
<p id="test" class="row">put stuff after here</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="debug-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">Click a tab to see one.</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```